# Liebert MPH SNMP Poweroff

Tags: snmp, power-distribution-unit

Super specific question, but here it goes.

We have several Liebert MPH rack PDU units with the necessary Liebert 'RPC' cards intalled to allow for SNMP polling.  Does anyone have experience with remotely powering off either a branch or receptacle using SNMP?  I've been digging through their MIBs for a while and have noticed that there are two interesting OIDs that *should* allow for poweroff, however my tests have been in vain.

MIB1: lgpPduRcpEntryControl : Can be set to poweroff, poweron, or reset a receptacle.

MIB2: lgpPduRcpEntryCapabilities : Displays the receptacle's capabilities, which can either be none, measurement, or measurement+control.  These are all set to just measurement.

The capabilities listed are just measurement, however this is a read-only OID which cannot be changed. I don't see any other options to allow for changes to this setting.  Anyone encounter this issue before?

Comment: Drop your answer as an Answer (you are allowed to answer your own questions), and mark it as accepted. That tells the system it has an answer, and others will find it just as easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liebert MPH model numbers that begin with MPH-NB are not controllable, they can only be monitored. Liebert MPH-NC models can be monitored and are controllable.  Note that they share the *same* MIB base, and SNMP sets will not error, they will appear to work. The SNMP server will respond saying the value is accepted.  Make sure to check the model number for sanity.